# App only crashes in certain devices ios8

Tags: xcode, crash, ios8, device

So I recently had my app rejected by Apple. This is what they said:

2.1: Apps that crash will be rejected
----- 2.1 -----

We found that your app crashed on iPad running iOS 8 and iPhone 5s running iOS 8, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

Your app crashed when we:

tapped on various menu items

If you have difficulty reproducing this issue, please try testing the workflow as described in Testing Workflow with Xcode's Archive feature.

I found it confusing why the app was only crashing on certain devices, especially the iPhone 5s. Since I don't personally own a 5s, I have been using the simulator and cannot recreate the crash. On the iPad retina simulator the app crashes when I press menu buttons and Xcode tells me the offending line is in the viewdidappear method of the view being segued FROM:

```
 if( adBanner != nil )
        {
            adBanner.removeFromSuperview()
            adBanner.delegate = nil
            adBanner = nil

        }
```

My questions are: How can I recreate these crashes on the iPhone 5s? How can I possibly fix this bug on the iPad or do I even need to? I assumed you could submit an app optimized to run on only certain iOS devices and that was determined by which devices you submitted screenshots for. Do I need this app to work for iPad or is there a way to just not publish it for iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mine was not also for ipad, but Apple still tested for that anyway.

I had the same issue. I was reproducing the issue on my ipad 2 when the project options is set to "link all assemblies" on my Xamarin project settings. The issue was not reproduced and the app on my ipad was working fine when I change options to only "link SDK assemblies only." This has been the reason with another app I published.

I'm going to try republishing the app again with that change in setting and hope for the best.

Answer (score 0):

```
How can I recreate these crashes on the iPhone 5s
```

An iPhone 5c might reproduce the issue, but your best bet is to use an iPhone 5s.  The simulator cannot possibly match behavior of the device when it comes to timing and memory characteristics.

You might be able to use guard malloc or NSZombies to find some issues related to memory mismanagement, so I suggest you try that out in the sim or on devices you own.

> Do I need this app to work for iPad or is there a way to just not
>   publish it for iPad?

You can build an iPhone-only app that will be run in compatibility mode on an iPad, but there's no way to prevent someone from running your iPhone app on an iPad.

Comment: So then there's no way to get apple to approve my app unless it doesn't work on iPad?

Comment: That question doesn't make sense.  Your app needs to work on iPad in order to be approved.  Just fix your crashes.

Comment: Im just a bit confused. I don't wish to submit this app for the iPad at all, I didn't submit any screenshots for iPad so I assumed thats how you let Apple know which devices you are submitting your app for (by which screenshots you submit). Is it apple policy that apps must work on all iOS devices or did I miss something? Also, I'm not so sure the problem has much to do with memory, I wrote the app in Swift which has memory management and the app runs fine on lesser hardware (iPhone 4s) as well as new hardware (iPhone 6). It's frustrating because I don't really know how to go about fixing this